# Link padding HTML email

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I have table with this markup:

```
<tr id="main_nav">
    <td style="width: 100%" colspan="2">
        <a>Link1</a>
        <a>Link2</a>
        <a>Link3</a>                            
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to set padding to these links, but I can't make it to work...
CSS:

```
#main_nav a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;  
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

What I've tried: wrap link into p tag, span tag, add css display block, display table, add style with padding to link.
Can not wrap each link in `<td>` tag!

**Edit:** Tried margin instead of padding, no luck.

Comment: I would say to have a look at [The Campaign Monitor Ultimate CSS Support Guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) as this outlines exactly what CSS is supported across email clients.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a wheel you're going to want to reinvent. Try this: https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `<a>Link1</a>` within a div, then set the div padding.

If it still doesn't work, try to change the width of the divs, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/XWLv6/1/

Comment: @Morpheus Can you add a jsfiddle example?

Comment: It's working when I am testing in browser. It doesn't in outlook.

Comment: I want these links to expand with table, but your example gave me idea to use percentage width and it worked :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

I successfully get around this issue by setting a large border to the same colour as the background.

```
border: 10px solid #fff;
```

Comment: This is genius!

Comment: @Seega thanks for that, you are very kind.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to consistently "pad" something in email is to just throw a couple of `&nbsp;` in there. Seems like bad practice I know...

Otherwise put them into their own table with an empty col as the padding for consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

add `display:block;` to the `#main_nav a`

Answer (score 0):

You must put your CSS inline for all elements in an HTML email. Example:

```
<a style="color:#fff;font-weight:bold;padding-left:1em;">Link1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's just matter of appearance this is what I did.

```
border-right-width: 177px;
border-left-width: 177px;
border-top-width: 10px;
border-bottom-width: 10px;
```